# Inapp mail service django and reactjs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am making some school management system in django and reactjs ,I want help in making inmail system so that teacher can send notice/attachment to the student of his/her class at once and it will be oneway communication. I wanted to build this but don't have any idea what technology to be use in django .

If anyone know the approach than please reply

Thanks